# How to compare two different multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two array as below

**Array 1**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ps_id] => 5
            [product_id] => 2
            [supplier_id] => 25
            [cost] => 789.00
            [name] => Mahesh
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ps_id] => 6
            [product_id] => 2
            [supplier_id] => 2
            [cost] => 12345.00
            [name] => mayank
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [ps_id] => 7
            [product_id] => 2
            [supplier_id] => 1
            [cost] => 123456.00
            [name] => abc
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [ps_id] => 10
            [product_id] => 2
            [supplier_id] => 8
            [cost] => 12000.00
            [name] => mayank1
        )
)
```

**Array 2**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [suppliers] => Mahesh
            [suppliers_cost] => 789.00
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [suppliers] => mayank
            [suppliers_cost] => 12345.00
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [suppliers] => mayank1
            [suppliers_cost] => 12000.00
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [suppliers] => testtetstet
            [suppliers_cost] => 123123
        )
)
```

I want to compare above array by their `suppliers` and `name` key,

Means if this both key have same values than it will store into one new array and if those key are not match then they will store new different array.

Or might be it possible that both array will have different number of keys

I had tried like below

```
foreach ($existsProductSupplier as $key => $value) {

     if (isset($supplier_data[$key])) {
     }else{
     $supplier_data[$key]['suppliers']='';
     $supplier_data[$key]['suppliers_cost']='';
     }
}

     foreach ($supplier_data as $key => $value) {       
       if(in_array($value['suppliers_cost'],$existsProductSupplier[$key])){
       //echo "string";
         // print_r($value);
      }else{
         echo "string";
         //print_r($value);
      }
    }
```

Comment: What had you tried yet?

Comment: "you have tried like below"... and the effect is? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

try this code it will help you

```
<?php

$arr1=Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            "ps_id" => 5,
            "product_id" => 2,
            "supplier_id" => 25,
            "cost" => 789.00,
            "name" => "Mahesh"
        ),
    1 => Array
        (
            "ps_id" => 6,
            "product_id" => 2,
            "supplier_id" => 2,
            "cost" => 12345.00,
            "name" => "mayank"
        ),
    2 => Array
        (
            "ps_id" => 7,
            "product_id" => 2,
            "supplier_id" => 1,
            "cost" => 123456.00,
            "name" => "abc"
        ),
    3 => Array
        (
            "ps_id" => 10,
            "product_id" => 2,
            "supplier_id" => 8,
            "cost" => 12000.00,
            "name" => "mayank1"
        ),
     4 => Array
        (
            "ps_id" => 10,
            "product_id" => 2,
            "supplier_id" => 8,
            "cost" => 12000.00,
            "name" => "mayank2"
        )
);


$arr2=Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            "suppliers" => "Mahesh",
            "suppliers_cost" => 789.00
        ),
    1 => Array
        (
            "suppliers" => "mayank",
            "suppliers_cost" => 12345.00
        ),
    2 => Array
        (
            "suppliers" => "mayank1",
            "suppliers_cost" => 12000.00
        ),
    3 => Array
        (
            "suppliers" => "testtetstet",
            "suppliers_cost" => 123123
        )
);

foreach($arr1 as $key=>$value){
    if(isset($arr2[$key])){
        if($value['name']==$arr2[$key]['suppliers']){
            $arrnew1[]=$value['name'];
        }else{
            $arrnew2[]=$value['name'];
        }    
    }else{
        $arrnew2[]=$value['name'];
    }

}
print_r($arrnew1);
print_r($arrnew2);
```

Comment: Thanks for response but different value can not store in new array :(;

Comment: so you want to store or not

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Mahesh
)
Array
(
    [0] => mayank
    [1] => abc
    [2] => mayank1
)

Comment: but its working array1 different  value store in newarray

Comment: and mayank is available in both array so its value is same